# Adding row to Table - Primary Key/Auto Increment Error(System.Data.SQLite)

Tags: c#, insert, primary-key, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to insert a new row into a database which has four fields, the first is a primary key set as auto incrementing (integer) and the other three are strings.

I insert a new with the following statement:

> INSERT INTO Manufacturer VALUES
>   ('Test1','Test2','01332232321')

But I am given the following exception:

> "SQLite error\r\ntable Manufacturer
>   has 4 columns but 3 values were
>   supplied"

I assumed that the primary key field can be omitted as the database would automatically assign and increment the value for me.

How would I go about fixing this? Is this a simple syntatical error or do I need to rethink my approach completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify columns:

```
INSERT INTO Manufacturer (col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('Test1','Test2','01332232321')
```

or pass the NULL value for primary key column.

Comment: Thanks, I never realised you had to specify the columns. I was working from http://www.sqlcommands.net/sql+insert/ and apparently missed the obvious part: "You are allowed to omit the list of column names in the SQL INSERT INTO clause, if you enter values for each of the table columns."

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for how to [AUTOINCREMENT in sqllite](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

also [How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)